# Select N random records with a limit of a certain category, if less rollover to next

Tags: mysql

I have a table and I try to retrieve a certain number of random entries and I want to put a certain maximum number of entries of a category at the top, followed by a certain number of another category.

If there is no entries in the first category, the allowed number of entries of it would be added to the number of entries of the 2sd category.

For example, my table has 3 categories (category: 'complete', 'partial', 'empty'). I want to display 12 entries in total.

For the "complete" category, I want to display 8. Then display 3 partials and finally 1 empty.

If there is less than 8 complete, let say there is 5, then it would display 5 complete, 6 partials and 1 empty. (missing 3 complete, so 3 base partials + 3 extra one = 6).

What would be the query to do that?

Here is the query I actually have:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
ORDER BY category='complete' DESC, category='partial' DESC, category DESC, RAND() ASC
LIMIT 12
```

The problem with the above query is that it gets 12 completes and it isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `USION DISTINCT` statement.

Try like this :

```
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = "complete" LIMIT 8)
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = "partial" LIMIT 3)
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = "" LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Yes, but what is there is less than 8 complete, it would not roll over to the next category. I am trying to always have 12 records displayed.

Comment: Hmm I presume it wont be really possible if you have less than 12 records in your db

Comment: Not exactly that. I have more than 12 records in my DB but not necessary 8 in the "complete" category.

Comment: Then the problem will be the same.